# How to convert vector of char to stringstream

Tags: c++, vector, stringstream

is it possible to convert char vector  to `std::stringstream`? For example:

```
std::vector<unsigned char> data;
std::stringstream st(????);
```

Is there any way  by which I can assign value of `data` to `st`?

Comment: i  tried "std::stringstream ss;
        std::string str(CL_Data.begin(),CL_Data.end());

        ss.str(str);"  it is working also but  i am looking for direct conversion from vector to stringstream

Answer (score 14, accepted):

If we look at the [`std::stringstream`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_stringstream/basic_stringstream) constructors, we see that the second one is:

```
explicit basic_stringstream( const std::basic_string<CharT,Traits,Allocator>& str,
                ios_base::openmode mode = ios_base::in|ios_base::out );
```

And the constructors of [`basic_string`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/basic_string) include:

```
template< class InputIt >
basic_string( InputIt first, InputIt last, 
              const Allocator& alloc = Allocator() );
```

Thus, we can do:

```
std::vector<unsigned char> data(20);

std::stringstream st(std::string(data.begin(), data.end()));
```

Answer (score 1):

Provided `vec` vector and `strstr` (o)stringstream:

```
copy(vec.begin(), vec.end(), ostream_iterator<char>(strstr));
```

Answer (score 1):

If you try to do:

```
std::stringstream st(data.data());
```

You will get this error from gcc:

> error: invalid user-defined conversion from 'unsigned char*' to 'const __string_type& {aka const std::basic_string&}' [-fpermissive]

Note that gcc is trying to convert the argument into a `std::string`.

[Barry](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2069064/barry) suggests explicitly constructing the `std::string` in his answer.

But *if your `std::vector<unsigned char> data` is null terminated* then you can leverage the implicit construction. You'll just need to change to something that a `std::string` can be constructed from.

```
std::stringstream st(reinterpret_cast<char*>(data.data()));
```

---

A potentially easier solution would be to change the type of `std::vector<unsigned char> data` to `std::vector<char> data`. In which case no cast is required:

```
std::stringstream st(data.data());
```

Comment: This code is inviting a read overrun -- the contents of the OP's `std::vector<unsigned char>` are NOT guaranteed to be null-terminated!

Comment: @LThode That's an excellent point that I hadn't considered. I've added the condition into the answer.